# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint Fail

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, sql-insert

So, to clarify things: I know why this is failing.
The question is: How to work around that?
This is my setup:
[image]
The referencing table is users and the referencing column is id, the referenced table is user_data, and the referenced column is id.
I want to store the email, username, salt and password in one table, but the user data like login tokens and such in another. I thought this was the right way to do it. Apparently I am missing something.

And oh I'm using PHP with PDO.

```
function registerUser($email, $username, $password)
{
    global $db;
    try {
        $prep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, username, salt, password) VALUES(':email', ':username', ':salt', ':password')");
        $salt = "abcd";
        $prep->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $prep->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $prep->bindParam(':salt', $salt);
        $prep->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $prep->execute();
        echo "Success";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot the error...
`Query failed: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`infokup2016`.`users`, CONSTRAINT`data`FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES`user_data`(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: How is it failing?  You need to provide us with the error messages you're getting, and the expected versus actual result.

Comment: maybe you are setting the foreign key in the 'wrong direction' ? You should set the foreign key on the user_data table, referencing the table users and not the contrary

Comment: I want it so that when I select the users table, I can get the user_data Contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the foreign key on the wrong table.

you have to set the foreign key on the field `id` of the table `user_data` referencing the filed `id` on the table `users`

Now you are trying to insert the data in the table `users`, but, as the `id` should be present in the table `user_data` (since you have a foreign key in the table `user` referencing the table `user_data`) it gives you the error

Comment: Well that was dumb of me, thanks for the help Moppo!